# Creating a new file with two columns of another flipped.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function re_order which, when run, reads a csv file and writes out the first 2 columns flipped on the second file. The delimiter is a comma and it is assumed there will always be 2 commas. The following is the test file:

```
Title,Author,Publisher,Year,ISBN-10,ISBN-13
Automate the Boring Stuff with Python,Al Sweigart,No Starch Press,2015,1593275994,978-1593275990
Dive into Python 3,Mark Pilgrim,Apress,2009,1430224150,978-1430224150
"Python Cookbook, Third edition","David Beazley, Brian K Jones",O'Reilly Media,2013,1449340377,978-1449340377
Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist,Allen B. Downey,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491939362,978-1491939369
"Fluent Python: Clear, Concise, and Effective Programming",Luciano Ramalho,O'Reilly Media,2015,1491946008,978-1491946008
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code even if it did not work, and any relevant error messages.

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking for. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you show the desired output? what you want in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function reorder takes a filepath as argument and creates a new file with only the first two columns flipped (in your case the title and author columns are flipped). Your question is too vague and I might have misunderstood the question. Let me know if you want a different output.

```
def reorder(in_file='books.csv', out_file='books_author.csv'):
    with open(in_file, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        fh = open(out_file, "w")
        for line in data:
            line = line.split(",")
            fh.write(line[1] + '  ' + line[0] +'\n')
        fh.close()
```

Comment: What does the line   fh = open("your_result.txt", "w") do?

Comment: It creates a new file by the name of your_result.txt. This would then contain the flipped columns of author and text. The "w" stands for write.

Comment: Would there be a way to alter the code so on the command line I could say something like re_order(in_file='books.csv', out_file='books_author.csv') in order to easily name the output file?